# How to fix make error "No rule to make target 'menuconfig'" when building a kernel for Beagleboard?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, angstrom

The aim is to build and install the USB Video Class (UVC) module, via `make modules_install`. I'm trying to configure the kernel via `make menuconfig` on Angstrom distribution, running on BeagleBoard-xM. Angstrom image (console only) was build on [Narcissus](http://narcissus.angstrom-distribution.org/) online image builder. Angstrom kernel is 2.6.32.

I receive the following error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.`

It seems that there are no kernel sources because `usr/src` contains nothing. Should I have to download Linux kernel 2.6.32 from kernel.org and what should be my next steps in order to configure the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the kernel and packages for embedded systems are built with a cross-compiler on desktop/server then they are packaged into one image and finally copied to the embedded system and flashed the SRAM or NAND/NOR Flash.

I personally like the [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org) distro which is easy to build.

Howto [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/linux)

Comment: I 'll have OpenEmbedded in mind. Do you have any suggestion in this case? Thank's anyway.

Comment: In your local config you should have the path to `~/oe/recipes/linux` where you have the regular bitbake build file and configure patches as needed. It's been a while since I touched this. Perhaps it is more convenient to use the build from beaglebone ore some alternatives like emdebian or openwrt debian etc.

Comment: @dempap: added also a howto link.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from `kernel.org` and extract it on `/usr/src/` after that you should copy existing kernel config from `/boot` to `/usr/src/linux-2.6.x/.config`. You can run :

```
 make menuconfig
```

Comment: Not sure about embedded systems, but menuconfig on x86/amd64 requires ncurses dev files and a few other packages.  If you have a known good config at /usr/src/linux/.config it may be easiest to run "make oldconfig"

Comment: You can use existing config from /boot/config-2.6.x and copied as .config.Sure, you should install all dependencies when you want to compile kernel from source code.